# how can i slove "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages." in laravel8

Tags: php, laravel

I use Laravel recently and when i run composer create-project
I'using ubuntu

This is what happens
[screen of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04Rj1.png)

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - phpunit/phpunit[9.5.10, ..., 9.5.x-dev] require ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
    - Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit ^9.5.10 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[9.5.10, 9.5.x-dev].
```

How do I fix that ?

Comment: sudo apt-get install php5-gd hen sudo apt-get install php5-intl and last one was sudo apt-get install php5-xsl

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the DOM extension for PHP. As you said you are using Ubuntu you can use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-dom
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to ignore platform requirements

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```